# com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer not found

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, content-delivery, tcdl

I am creating/extending a simple TCDL tag following this link: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/cleaning-and-extending-dynamic-linking

However, the IMPORT statement: `import com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer;` is having error as not found. I have added all possible JAR files references to my Java project(in Eclipse). All the JAR files were taken from the `lib` folder of my tridion website.

Below is the Error shown. Which JAR file am I missing ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer` is available in the `cd_dynamic.jar`, and it can be found in your SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 installation media under `Content Delivery\roles\api\java\lib`.

Basically for we website you should have the following jars from the above mentioned location:

- `cd_ambient.jar`
- `cd_broker.jar`
- `cd_cache.jar`
- `cd_core.jar`
- `cd_datalayer.jar`
- `cd_dynamic.jar`
- `cd_linking.jar`
- `cd_model.jar`
- `cd_tcdl.jar`
- `cd_wai.jar`

Next to that you will also need all 37 jars from the `Content Delivery\roles\api\java\third-party-lib` folder.

Comment: Can you please confirm atleast for this solution i am developing adding cd_dynamic.jar is required for now? Is all other 37 jars also must be referenced by my solution ?

Comment: I can confirm that if you need to implement a `TagRenderer` you will need to import `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer` which means you need to reference the `cd_dynamic.jar` in your project, and that jar has dependencies on other jars etc. etc., so you should reference all 10 jars from the `lib` folder and all 37 jars from the `third-party-lib` in order to be able to compile your project.

Comment: Thank you very much Bart. I understand now how these dependencies work